# Javascript Objects. Instantiation of an object as the property value of an object

Tags: javascript, object, scope, instantiation, encapsulation

I'm having some issues wrapping my head around object instantiation and scope in JavaScript...

Looking at this sample code:

```
someOtherObj = {
  aMethod: function() {
    $('body').append('aMethod successfully called!<br>');
    return 'd';
  }
}

// THIS WORKS!!
$('body').append(someOtherObj.aMethod() + '<br>');

someObj = {
  aValue: 'a',
  bValue: 'b',
  cValue: this.aValue,              // THIS DOESN'T WORK!!
  dValue: new someOtherObj(),       // THIS DOESN'T WORK!!
  eValue: {
    fValue: aValue,                 // THIS DOESN'T WORK!!
    gValue: this.aValue,            // THIS DOESN'T WORK!!
    hValue: someObj.aValue,         // THIS DOESN'T WORK!!
  },
};

// JavaScript crashes out before this, but...
// This should result in:  'a'
$('body').append(someObj.cValue + '<br>');

// This should result in:  'd'
$('body').append(someObj.dValue.aMethod() + '<br>');

// These should result in: 'a'
$('body').append(someObj.eValue.fValue + '<br>');
$('body').append(someObj.eValue.gValue + '<br>');
$('body').append(someObj.eValue.hValue + '<br>');
```

I think the comments are pretty self explanatory... But that being said:

1. How can I make `cValue` *reference* (`===`) `aValue`, and/or have the same value (`==`) as `aValue`?
2. How can I *instantiate* a new object as the property of another object?
3. How can I access the property of a containing object?

Comment: You can't refer to an under-construction object inside the object literal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make `cValue` reference (`===`) `aValue`, and/or have the same value (`==`) as `aValue`?

You can't (other than just using the same value to initialize it, e.g. `cValue: 'a'`); more here: [*Self references in object literal declarations*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations).

Alternately, you could make `cValue` a *getter* that returns `aValue`, though there's little point in this case:

```js
var obj = {
    aValue: 42,
    get cValue() {
        return this.aValue;
    }
};
console.log(obj.cValue); // 42
obj.aValue = 67;
console.log(obj.cValue); // 67
```

> How can I instantiate a new object as the property of another object?

The way you're doing it. The problem with what you're doing (`new someOtherObj()`) is that `someOtherObj` is an *object*, not a *constructor function*. (Constructor functions are objects, but most objects aren't constructor functions.)

This is a constructor function:

```
function Example() {
    this.someProperty = "some value"; // This bit is optional; it's here to
                                      // emphasize that constructors initialize
                                      // the contents of the new object
}
```

so is this, via ES2015 `class` syntax:

```
class Example {
    constructor() {
        this.someProperty = "some value"; // Again, this bit is optional
    }
}
```

In both cases, this works:

```
var obj {
    example: new Example()
};
console.log(example.someProperty); // "some value"
```

> How can I access the property of a containing object?

Via `this`, if the code that's running is called in a way that sets `this` to the object. For instance:

```
var obj = {
    answer: 42,
    doSomething: function() {
        console.log(this.answer);
    }
};
obj.doSomething(); // 42
```

See these questions and their answers:

- [*How does the "this" keyword work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)
- [*How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) *(for advice around a common pitfall)

Or in the case of one-off objects like that, by using the name of the variable they're assigned to:

```
var obj = {
    answer: 42,
    doSomething: function() {
        console.log(obj.answer); // <== Only change is here
    }
};
obj.doSomething(); // 42
```

Answer (score -1):

It is my understanding that `this` is dependent on the execution context.  Also, it cannot be used in assignment.  In other words:

```
var obj0 = {
    self: this // <--refers to the global object
}

var obj1 = {
    'use strict'
    self: this // undefined
}
```

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this